# PHP form submission to self failed to load

Tags: php, validation, session-variables

I have customized a php form code by adding a captcha which I expected to show the errors on the form itself instead of using the die command to show it to another page or pop up dialogue. I used PHP sesssion instead of Ajax. I am having following problems.

1) After clicking the submit button, the browser address bar shows the processing php file path but it fails to load the form again following the header command, just showing a blank screen. Previously, it was able to load the form with error codes and the captcha worked just fine. I don't know what went wrong.

2) strangely, if I press the browser back button, the form loads as it was left. And when i reload the form to start again, instead of clearing the form, it starts to show error message but only one error message at a time! (but I want to show all error messages at once if multiple fields are empty or filled with wrong type of character.) Why would a form process data up on refreshing the page? Shouldn't it only happen when the submit button is pressed?

3) Despite the loading problem, I am still getting email, with empty fields!

Please help.

The contactform.php code is given below:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form action="php/contact.php" method="post" id="frmContact">

<h5 style="color: #ffffff;">What's your Name?</h5>
<input name="txtName" type="text" class="txbx" value="" />
<?php echo $_SESSION[lmsg_name]; ?><br />

<h5 style="color: #ffffff;">What's your Email?</h5>
<input name="txtEmail" type="text" class="txbx" value="" />
<?php echo $_SESSION[lmsg_email]; ?><br />

<h5 style="color: #ffffff;">Email Subject?</h5>
<input name="txtSubject" type="text" class="txbx" value="" />
<?php echo $_SESSION[lmsg_subject]; ?><br />

<h5 style="color: #ffffff;">Message to us</h5>
<textarea name="txtText" class="txbx era" placeholder="" ></textarea>
<?php echo $_SESSION[lmsg_text]; ?><br />

<h5 style="color: #ffffff;">Enter verification code</h5>
<img src="php/captcha.php" style="float:left; margin-left: 11px; margin-right: 10px;   margin-top: 5px;" >
<input type="text" name="vercode" class="txbxcap" />
<?php echo $_SESSION[lmsg_incode]; ?><br />

<input name="" type="submit" class="sendbtn" value="SEND MESSAGE" id="btnSend"/>

</form>
<?php
$_SESSION[lmsg_name] ='';
$_SESSION[lmsg_email] ='';
$_SESSION[lmsg_subject] ='';
$_SESSION[lmsg_text] ='';
$_SESSION[lmsg_incode] ='';
?>
```

The captcha.php code is given below:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$text = rand(10000,99999); 
$_SESSION["vercode"] = $text; 
$height = 38; 
$width = 55; 

$image_p = imagecreate($width, $height); 
$black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0); 
$white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255); 
$font_size = 16; 

imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 5, $text, $white); 
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 80); 
?>
```

The processing contact.php is given below:

```
<?php

session_start(); 

$Name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtName']);
$Email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtEmail']);
$Subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtSubject']);
$Text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txtText']);

$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';


if (empty ($Name) || !preg_match($string_exp,$Name)) { 
$error_name = '<div style="color: #e44558; float:left; margin-left: 11px;">*Please provide a name.<br /></div>';
$_SESSION[lmsg_name] = $error_name;
header('Location:http:../contactform.php');
}

elseif (empty ($Email) || !preg_match($email_exp,$Email)) { 
$error_email = '<div style="color: #e44558; float:left; margin-left: 11px;">*Please enter a valid email address.<br /></div>';
$_SESSION[lmsg_email] = $error_email;
header('Location:http:../contactform.php');
}

elseif (empty ($Subject) ||!preg_match($string_exp,$Subject)) {
$error_subject = '<div style="color: #e44558; float:left; margin-left: 11px;">*Please provide a subject.<br /></div>';
$_SESSION[lmsg_subject] = $error_subject;
header('Location:http:../contactform.php');
}

elseif (empty ($Text) ||!preg_match($string_exp,$Text)) {
$error_text = '<div style="color: #e44558; float:left; margin-left: 11px;">*Please write few words...<br /></div>';
$_SESSION[lmsg_text] = $error_text;
header('Location:http:../contactform.php');
}

elseif ($_POST["vercode"] != $_SESSION["vercode"] OR $_SESSION["vercode"]=='') { 
$error_code = '<div style="color: #e44558; float:left; margin-left: 11px;">*Incorrect verification code. Please try again.<br /></div>';
$_SESSION[lmsg_incode] = $error_code;
header('Location:http:../contactform.php');
}

else {

//create email
$email_to = "x@y.com";
$email_subject = "Visitor Query: ". $Subject;
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($Name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($Email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($Text)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$Email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$Email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);     


header('location:../contact_thnx.html');
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Fix your PHP syntax errors. `$_SESSION[foo]` is semi-illegal. PHP will politely convert that undefined constant `foo` to a string `'foo'` for you, but will issue a ton of warnings. It should be `$_SESSION['foo']`. And your header redirects are suspect too. you can't just have `http:../` as your url.  if you're including a protocol, then it should be `http://servername/path`

Comment: The real problem is in the header typo. Valid Location header is as follow: "Location:[SPACE][path]".

Comment: Plus, from a usability standpoint, this form sucks. Why redirect at the first sign of an error? You'd be forcing the user to re-do the form once for every single error in there. miss 3 fields - get forced to fix the form 3 times. Why not check ALL of the fields first, then redirect ONCE if any errors occured?

Comment: don't forget to add `exit();` after your `header();` function call.

Comment: Thanks Marc B for the suggestion. I tried with full URL but it didn't work. I have probably already tried with the space between location: and path but i'll look into it again. Regarding the redirection at the first sign of error, how do I show all errors at once? Can you give me a hint please? Remove header command from the if/elseif {} and put it in another condition? I know that the code is not right, and that's why I posted for help...I searched this site but couldn't find a better php form code without the use of 'die()' redirection. Thanks.